How to find local maxima or minima or global maximum or minimum of $y= \vert x \vert$
A critical point is where the derivative ($\dfrac{dy}{dx}$) is either zero or undefined.
For $y = \vert x \vert$, the absolute value function can be broken down into two parts:

$x > 0: y = x$ (straight line with positive slope)
$x < 0: y = -x$ (straight line with negative slope)

The transition between these two parts happens at $x = 0$. The derivative of $\vert x \vert$ is:

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 1$ for $x > 0$
$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -1$ for $x < 0$

Therefore, the derivative is undefined (and thus we have a critical point) at $x = 0$.
Analyze the function around the critical point:
The critical point here is $x = 0$. We can analyze the sign of the derivative on either side of this point:

For $x < 0$ (left of the critical point), $\frac{dy}{dx} = -1$ (negative slope), so the function is decreasing.

For $x > 0$ (right of the critical point), $\frac{dy}{dx} = 1$ (positive slope), so the function is increasing.


Determine extrema:
Since the function changes direction from decreasing to increasing at $x = 0$, it has a local minimum at $x = 0$.
((Now problem is how to conclude global maximum or minimum for this function))

The function doesn’t have a global maximum.  Suppose $M$ is the maximum.  $f(M) = M$.  But $f(M+h) > m$ for any positive $h.$  If we restrict the function to a closed and bounded domain, then it will have a maximum and a minimum.  But if the domain is an open set, then there is no guarantee that a max or a min exists.

The derivative is indeed undefined at $x=0$, but: 1) this is not a consequence of the fact that it is $1$ at any $x>0$ and $-1$ at any $x<0$ (though I guess that this is not what you meant and that your thinking is correct) 2) This is useless for the conclusion that there is a global min at $0$.

This is a repost  of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4927468, which the asker should have improved instead, to ask for its undeletion and reopening.

The poster has also changed his/her username to hide that fact. Is it that difficult to grasp that $|x|\ge 0$ so that the global minimum must be at least $0$ and that from $|0|=0$ it follows what that global minimum is?

I’m voting to close this question because it is a repost.

Anyone who tries to use derivatives to find local/global maxima/minima of $f(x)=|x|$ should really be asking, what do the terms "local/global maxima/minima" mean? because said person surely doesn't know. Either that, or said person knows nothing about $f(x)=|x|$.

"Since the function changes direction from decreasing to increasing at $x=0$
, it has a local minimum at $x=0$
." Better said (and everything else was useless):

Since $f$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,0]$ and increasing on $[0,\infty)$, it has a global minimum at $x=0$ (and no other local minimum, and no maximum at all).

The fact that $f$ is monotonic on each of these two closed half lines (and not only on the open ones) is justified by (the sign of $f'$ at any $x\ne0$, and) the continuity of $f$ at $0$.

What's about global maximum?

My "no maximum at all" (which is a consequence of what preceeds) means: no local (and a fortiori no global) maximum.
